# Overlay audio while recording in Swift

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation, record, openal

I would like to know the best Audio API in Swift for iOS for the following 3 problems:

1. How to play what is recorded at the same time (i.e. make the recorded voice play immediately to headphones on the same iOS-device).
2. Overlay several audio-files and play them all at once.
3. Overlay the overlayed audio-files and the recorded voice all at once

Any idea appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for this?  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioengine

Comment: Thank you, Harvey, I'll definitively give it a try and learn about AVAudioEngine... Do you know, by chance, if AVAudioEngine can record and play at the same time ?